# Debugging C code that uses libtiff

Tags: c, codeblocks, libtiff

I've written a lot of code over the years, but I haven't done much with C in the context of linux. Nor am I as familiar as I feel I should be with someone of the tools and utilities. Thanks in advance for your indulgence.

I'm trying to write some C code that uses libtiff. I need to be able to debug it line by line, including stepping through the libtiff source as appropriate. I'm using the Code::Blocks IDE and have that configured and working for basic "hello world" code, as well as a rudimentary calling of libtiff for proof-of-concept purposes. This is all working.

Here's my code:

```
#include "tiffio.h"
main()
    {
    TIFF* tif = TIFFOpen("test0.tiff", "r");
    if (tif) {
        uint32 imagelength;
        tdata_t buf;
        uint32 row;

        TIFFGetField(tif, TIFFTAG_IMAGELENGTH, &imagelength);
        buf = _TIFFmalloc(TIFFScanlineSize(tif));
        for (row = 0; row < imagelength; row++)
            TIFFReadScanline(tif, buf, row, 0);
        _TIFFfree(buf);
        TIFFClose(tif);
        }
}
```

Stepping through my code above works fine. However, I can't step into any
of the libtiff function calls. I'm currently on ubuntu, using the default libtiff installed via **apt-get**. I'm assuming based on some reading I've done that the library isn't built with debugging symbols, which may be the source of my problem.

I'm assuming if that's indeed the problem, that I can compile a custom version of libtiff with the options I need, and have Code::Blocks compile/link against it instead of against the system default libraries. I've downloaded a fresh copy of libtiff, and am familiar with the make/make install process, but I'm not sure about the specifics of getting the compile set up properly for what I need. Some direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Usually Debian has `-dbg` packages with debug symbols, use `apt-cache search libtiff` to see whether there is a libtiff-gdb package. If not, then you would have to build yourself libtiff with -g in the CFLAGS. I don't know whether there are -dbg packages for all libs.

Comment: Did you try to use `gdb`?

Comment: OK, I got it working. Uninstalled the system libtiff, and setup code blocks to compile/link against my local copy complied with -g in CFLAGS as suggested above. Now stepping through libtiff sources as desired. had to tell code blocks where everything was (Project->Build Options menu) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved by uninstalling the system libtiff (not strictly necessary but was easiest for me to avoid any ambiguity on what version of libtiff I was using). Then configured Code::Blocks as follows (Project->Build Options):

- Produce debubging symbols (-g) is checked
- Enable common compiler warnings is checked
- Other Compiler Options set to **-fPIC**
- Linker Settings -> Other Linker Options set to **-ltiff -L**
- Search Directories -> Compiler set to
- Search Directories -> Linker set to
- $LD_LIBRARY_PATH set to **/home/depaan/amcdev/libtiff0/lib** in Settings -> Environment -> Environment Variables (menu)

I'd previously complied libtiff locally as per the usual configure, make, make install... with

```
./configure --prefix=<desired_libtiff_location>
```

And CFLAGS set to "-g"

```
export CFLAGS="-g"
```